# create intellij project and modules programmatically

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a large project with many large directory structure. They produce around 90 JARs. The IntelliJ project structure is not the same (or similar) to the one seen by Ant scripts. This creates a lot of problems while editing the code. Main side effect is incorrect dependencies get added. Essentially I am looking to create a one-jar one-module mapping

Is it possible to create Intellij modules programmatically?   I can re-use existing set of libraries, created in IntelliJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@CrazyCoder is right using maven would be a better solution, but that conversation may just be a little bit too much to swallow.

The `.iml` files are just xml and while it isn't documented it is pretty understandable. It shouldn't be the trickest thing to create a template and then use either ant property replacement or a custom task to generate these files for each module.

For reference you may want to look at the source for the [maven-idea-plug](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/) it generates `.iml` files for a maven project and may provide you with a hint on how todo this with ant. Note that @CrazyCoder points out the comments that this should only be a reference...don't use this for maven support in Idea.

Comment: Note that this plug-in generates incorrect projects in some cases and you can get weird errors in IDEA, we don't recommend using it, built-in Maven support works more reliably. You are right, it can be a good reference if one wants to generate IDEA projects by hand, but it's more complicated than using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: I completely agree with you on maven.. the idea maven support is easily the best in any IDE i have seen. But converting a 90 module/jar ant build to maven isn't for the faint hearted :)

Answer (score 5):

Please consider using Maven or Gradle instead, IDEA supports both. Maven support is more mature, Gradle support will improve in the future updates.

Your Maven projects will work with all the major IDEs and command line, not just IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: +1 I've got a new feature request ... a Maven to Gradle Converter for IntelliJ IDEA would be incredibly helpful for CI